# Converting JSON between string and byte[] with GSON

Tags: java, arrays, json, hibernate, gson

I'm using hibernate to map objects to the database. A client (an iOS app) sends me particular objects in JSON format which I convert to their true representation using the following utility method:

```
/**
     * Convert any json string to a relevant object type
     * @param jsonString the string to convert
     * @param classType the class to convert it too
     * @return the Object created
     */
    public static <T> T getObjectFromJSONString(String jsonString, Class<T> classType) {
        
        if(stringEmptyOrNull(jsonString) || classType == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert null or empty json to object");
        }

        try(Reader reader = new StringReader(jsonString)){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            return gson.fromJson(reader, classType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.error("Unable to close the reader when getting object as string", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The issue however is, that in my pogo I store the value as a byte[] as can be seen below (as this is what is stored in the database - a blob):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonalCard")
public class PersonalCard implements Card{
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    private int userid;
    
    @Column(name = "homephonenumber")
    protected String homeContactNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "mobilephonenumber")
    protected String mobileContactNumber;
    
    @Column(name = "photo")
    private byte[] optionalImage;
    
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
```

Now of course, the conversion fails because it can't convert between a byte[] and a String.

Is the best approach here to change the constructor to accept a String instead of a byte array and then do the conversion myself whilst setting the byte array value or is there a better approach to doing this.

The error thrown is as follows;

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 96 path
> $.optionalImage

Thanks.

**Edit** In fact even the approach I suggested will not work due to the way in which GSON generates the object.

Comment: What is the problem? Can't you serialize/deserialize byte array using json format? Or what?

Comment: i am receiving an object as json and directly converting it in to my hibernate pojo. the hibernate pojo works in byte array format. the GSON library converts string to object and seems to be failing to convert the byte[]

Comment: What is the error on that fail?

Comment: have added to the OP

Comment: maybe this can help you [link](https://gist.github.com/orip/3635246)

Comment: that did work user23123412 - thanks

Comment: @Biscuit128 does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628603/extracting-a-byte-array-from-a-json) one help you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use this [adapter](https://gist.github.com/orip/3635246) to serialize and deserialize byte arrays in base64.
Here's the content.

```
   public static final Gson customGson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class,
            new ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter()).create();

    // Using Android's base64 libraries. This can be replaced with any base64 library.
    private static class ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<byte[]>, JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {
        public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return Base64.decode(json.getAsString(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }

        public JsonElement serialize(byte[] src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeToString(src, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    }
```

Credit to the author [Ori Peleg](https://gist.github.com/orip).

Comment: I have a HashMap<String, byte[]> - it doesn't seem to work right with the adapter toJson - I get Java object references and not the target base64 values. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**From some blog for future reference, incase the link is not available, atleast users can refer here.**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;

public class GsonHelper {
    public static final Gson customGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
                @Override
                public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                return new Date(json.getAsLong());
                }
            })
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(byte[].class,
                    new ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter()).create();

    // Using Android's base64 libraries. This can be replaced with any base64 library.
    private static class ByteArrayToBase64TypeAdapter implements JsonSerializer<byte[]>, JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {
        public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            return Base64.decode(json.getAsString(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }

        public JsonElement serialize(byte[] src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeToString(src, Base64.NO_WRAP));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed the solution to comply with the [OpenAPI specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#format) that states String type of format byte has to hold base64 encoded values. POJO holds byte[] and JSON object has String property.

In my case I couldn't use android library for base64 processing as Gson serialization was used in backend application. For this reason I used java provided **java.util.Base64** class.

Instead of adapter based on JsonSerializer<byte[]>, JsonDeserializer<byte[]> interfaces I used  **TypeAdapter<byte[]>** adapter. With it I could override HTML escaping functionality of Gson to prevent escaping padding character '=' in base64 encoding. If this isn't done then encoded value of "hello World"would be *"aGVsbG8gV29ybGQ\u003d"* instead of *"aGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="* and deserializer on other side would fail.

Below is the code of custom adapter:

```
public class ByteArrayAdapter extends TypeAdapter<byte[]> {

  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter out, byte[] byteValue) throws IOException {
    boolean oldHtmlSafe = out.isHtmlSafe();
    try {
      out.setHtmlSafe(false);
      out.value(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteValue)));
    } finally {
      out.setHtmlSafe(oldHtmlSafe);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] read(JsonReader in) {
    try {
      if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
        in.nextNull();
        return new byte[]{};
      }
      String byteValue = in.nextString();
      if (byteValue != null) {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(byteValue);
      }
      return new byte[]{};
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new JsonParseException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, (JsonSerializer<byte[]>) (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(new String(src)))
        .registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, (JsonDeserializer<byte[]>) (json, typeOfT, context) -> json == null ? null : json.getAsString() == null ? null : json.getAsString().getBytes())
        .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the photo as String in POJO , and in Setter method convert String to byte[] and return  byte[] in Getter method

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PersonalCard")
public class PersonalCard implements Card
{

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    private int userid;

    @Column(name = "homephonenumber")
    protected String homeContactNumber;

    @Column(name = "mobilephonenumber")
    protected String mobileContactNumber;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    private byte[] optionalImage;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column
    byte[] optionalImage;

    public byte[] getOptionalImage()
    {
        return optionalImage;
    }

    public void setOptionalImage(String s)
    {
        this.optionalImage= s.getBytes();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not how we should do it.