# Way to deserialize the byte array in spring java

Tags: spring, arrays, deserialization, image-uploading, json-deserialization

I doing project to upload the image, for that I converted the image into base64 string, now in my DTO i have deserialized the byte array as follows :

```
class DecodePhoto extends JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {
    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext arg1)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String data = jsonparser.getText();

        try {
            byte[] decodedBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(data);

            return decodedBytes;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

After ajax call in image, I have got the following error as follows :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)

What is the problem here? I have attached jar **common-codec-1.9.jar** and **jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar**

But in debugging mode (Class File Editor) it shows as follows

> **The JAR file jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar has no source attachment.**

Kindly do me favour to deserialize the byte array ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522309/converting-json-between-string-and-byte-with-gson/25523772#25523772) may help you

Answer (score 0):

I have decoded the byte array using `.decodeBase64(byte[])` instead of `.decodeBase64(String)`.

**Reason :** Because the method `.decodeBase64(final String base64String)` is used in `common-codec-1.4` version but I am using `common-codec-1.9` version , hence I used `.decodeBase64(byte[])`.

```
class DecodePhoto extends JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext arg1)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String data = jsonparser.getText();

        try {

            byte[] decodedBytes = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(**data.getBytes()**);  // here is the major change

            return decodedBytes;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```