# IllegalStateException - Serializing a map with a String array using Gson

Tags: java, hashmap, gson

Here is the full error I am receiving:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $.
```

The map I am trying to encode is a

```
HashMap<String[],Boolean>.
```

I use this to serialize the map:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(object);
```

and this to deserialize the object:

```
json.fromJson(encodedObject, new TypeToken<HashMap<String[], Boolean>>(){}.getType())
```

This is the raw JSON output:

```
{
     "[Ljava.lang.String;@433fe238":false,
     "[Ljava.lang.String;@433feb38":false,
     "[Ljava.lang.String;@433fe018":false,
     "[Ljava.lang.String;@433fd618":false
}
```

I have other maps that I encode and decode in a similar way, but this is the only one that is giving me issues. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I can't help you with the Gson problem as I have no experience with it, but I do see one crucial problem you might want to address. An array can't be used very well as a `HashMap` key. Arrays don't have a well behaved `hashCode()` and `equals()`. Use a `List<String>`.

Comment: Anyway, I Googled and your problem seems to be the same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522309/converting-json-between-string-and-byte-with-gson

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This old code that I am trying to fix and I can't really change the data structure without some problems. I was a bit of a novice when I wrote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unfortunate you can't change the type of elements in the data-structure. You should likely never store arrays as keys as they don't override equals, hashcode and toString.

That said let's talk about your error. It's due to the fact that Gson serialize the key as a String, because the JSON grammar requires that in a key-value pair, the key must be a string. But you expect an array as a key so the parser throws the error.

Since you cannot change the structure, you can write a custom serializer and deserializer to handle this:

```
class MapSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Map<String[], Boolean>> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Map<String[], Boolean> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String[], Boolean> entry : src.entrySet()) {
            obj.addProperty(Arrays.toString(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
        }
        return obj;
    }
}

class MapDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<String[], Boolean>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String[], Boolean> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Map<String[],Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
            String s = entry.getKey();
            //See how you're dependent of the String representation given by Arrays.toString? 
            //Not very convenient.
            map.put(s.substring(1, s.length()-1).split(", "), entry.getValue().getAsBoolean());
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Basically the key is now given by `Arrays.toString`, which is a readable representation of the elements in the array, instead of its `toString` method.

But as you see the deserialization process has to assume that this representation won't change, this is quite risky as any modification in the result of `Arrays.toString` would break the process, but you have to deal with it... (although it's unlikely to happen but this is a fact that you have to be aware of)

To make this work, you need to register the adapters in the parser.

```
Map<String[],Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new String[]{"Hello"},false);
map.put(new String[]{"Stack", "Overflow"},true);

Type t = new TypeToken<Map<String[], Boolean>>(){}.getType();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(t, new MapSerializer())
                             .registerTypeAdapter(t, new MapDeserializer())
                             .setPrettyPrinting()
                             .create();

String repr =  gson.toJson(map, t);
Map<String[], Boolean> map2 = gson.fromJson(repr, t);
```

If you try to print `repr`, you'll get:

```
{
  "[Hello]": false,
  "[Stack, Overflow]": true
}
```

which is better than your original output. You get back the "same" map with `fromJson` (I quoted "same" because the keys are equals according to `Arrays.equals` not `.equals()`).

Hope it helps!

Comment: So I did play around with this a bit and did actually change the structure in the end, from a map to a list. That seems to work, even though the list still contains the string array.

Comment: @rioneye If its more convenient to use a Map, you could create a wrapper class around the array which overrides toString with `Arrays.toString`, hashcode with `Arrays.hashCode` and equals with `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: @rioneye Then you would only have to write the deserializer and you will have the control of the `toString` implementation of the wrapper. And `map.equals(map2)` would give you true of course. You can find an implementation there if needed: https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/3585ca1916a426a816c7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write a `toString()` method for `String[]`,or you will only get the address of every String[]