# json Can not deserialize value of type byte from String

Tags: java, json, jackson

In Spring java application, I am receiving REST json request with following input where 'mode' field is defined as byte in the java class.

```
{
  "application": "sadsd",
  "date": "20161109",
  "mode": "A",
  "catalogId": 0,
}
```

pojo -

```
public class Test {
  String application;
  String date;
  byte mode;
  int catalogId;
...
}
```

getting Following error -

```
"exception": org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type byte from String \"A\":
not a valid Byte value\n at 
[Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6386b197; line: xx, column: xx] 
(through reference chain: com.abc.myInput[\"mode\"]); 

`enter code here`nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException:
Can not deserialize value of type byte from String \"A\":

not a valid Byte value\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6386b197; line: xx, column: xx] 
(through reference chain: com.abc.myInput[\"mode\"])",`
```

Do i have to write serializer and deserializer here?

Are there any annotations that i can use on byte field or get/set methods of that field without writing any additional code?

Comment: Why can't the model use a String variable? JSON has no concept of a byte array. You could maybe write your setters and getters to use the constructors of the String class to use byte arrays

Comment: As model is generated and used by many others , altering datatype is not an option.

Comment: Then you'll need a custom deserializer.

Comment: I know this is a little long winded but you can use GSON and write a little byte[] adapter.  Check out this posting - it pretty much hands it to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522309/converting-json-between-string-and-byte-with-gson

Comment: what if you have a file object that you're taking as a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just went ahead with declaring them as String and taking first byte from input string and converting byte to string for the output. 
Thanks for the input cricket_007 and jnbbender.

Comment: can you plz give example?