# Can not deserialize value of type int from String

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring

This is the full error that I get in the console:

> "Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type int from
>   String "${product.id}": not a valid Integer value↵ at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@40d1a098; line: 1, column: 14] (through
>   reference chain: haughton.dvdstore.model.AddToCartPojo["productId"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   deserialize value of type int from String "${product.id}": not a valid
>   Integer value↵ at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@40d1a098; line:
>   1, column: 14] (through reference chain:
>   haughton.dvdstore.model.AddToCartPojo["productId"])"

My html

```
<form  method="post">
<p>Enter quantity you would like to purchase :
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" step="any" min="1" max="${product.quantityInStock}" value="1"></input>
 </p>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="addToCart"  name="button" value="Add to cart"/>
<input type="hidden" id="productId" value='${product.id}'/>
</form>
```

App.js

```
  $("#addToCart").click(function(event) {

        var data = {}
        data["productId"] = $("#productId").val();
       data["quantity"] = $("#quantity").val();



        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 url: "http://localhost:8080/addToCart",
                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 timeout: 600000,
                 success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                     //...
                 },
                 error: function (e) {

                     //...
                 }
        });
     event.preventDefault();

    });
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class CartController {
@Autowired
private Cart cart;
@Autowired
ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value="/cart", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchResults(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("cartLines",cart.getLines());
model.addAttribute("cartTotalPrice",cart.getTotalPrice());
    return "cart";
}
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/addToCart", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchResults(@RequestBody AddToCartPojo addToCartPojo) {
    Product product = productService.findById(((long) addToCartPojo.getProductId()));
    if(product == null){
        //if the productid supplied doesnt belong to a product in our database
        return "failure";
    }
    FlashMessage result = cart.add(product,addToCartPojo.getQuantity());
      return  result.getStatus().toString();
}
```

AddToCartPojo

```
//pojo for sending via ajax
public class AddToCartPojo {
private int productId;
private int quantity;

public int getProductId() {
    return productId;
}

public void setProductId(int productId) {
    this.productId = productId;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

}

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533887/json-can-not-deserialize-value-of-type-byte-from-string] you can check this link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest altering your `AddToCartPojo` so that `productId` is a `String` instead of an `int`:

So change this :

```
private int productId;
```

To this :

```
private String productId;
```

You'll need to change your getters 'n' setters too.